# get absolute path into a shell script variable

Tags: shell-script

I have inherited a shell script (`#!/usr/bin/sh` and I am not allowed to change the shell; i.e I can't, for instance, use a `bash` solution)).

It references a file in a relative path e.g `DIR=$PWD/../SOME_DIR`.

When I `echo $DIR` the output is something like `/home/user/scripts/../SOME_DIR`.

How can I get the absolute path name (no `..`) into a variable (to be used in a  later `echo`)? I.e `/home/user/SOME_DIR`

It has been a few decades since my last shell script, and Google is not my friend today

Comment: Does it actually contain `DIR = ` with the spaces around `=`? If you can't modify it, how did you do `ECHO $DIR`, and did you actually use `ECHO` in all-caps?

Comment: I am an idiot, who should not be allowed to post. No spaces around `=` in the assignment, Not sure what you mean about non-modification, and lower case `echo`. My bad. Question updated (and comment upvoted). Thanks

Comment: So when you say "I am not allowed to change it", you mean you can't change the `#! /usr/bin/sh`? I thought you meant you couldn't modify the file itself.

Comment: `$PWD/../SOME_DIR` is already an absolute path, not a relative path. Could you clarify your question a bit please?

Comment: @mnu, yup, that's what I meant. I will update the question. |I was just trying to suggest that I couldn't for instance , use a `bash` solution

Comment: @Kusalananda as soon as I see `..` I consider it to be a relative path. I am probably wrong in that, but it's how I look at it. What I meant was no `..` to seen on the path. I have edited the question to clarify. Thanks

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica This is very late, but just to clarify: Relative paths depend on your current directory, i.e. they are relative to the path you are currently at. Absolute paths are beginning with root `/` and resolve to the same destination regardless of your current location. Paths containing `..` are not resolved yet, but are not dependent on where you are now, so they are absolute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`realpath` returns the resolved (absolute) path of whatever path you call it with:

```
absdir=$(realpath "$DIR")
echo $absdir
```

prints `/home/user/SOME_DIR`

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much